# Passing string element to data key

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, for-loop, split

I have a function that checks for a div, and if it exists it fills it with the matching data from a JSON array. The Div and the data have the same id & key, so I want to be able to put those in a string for a more elegant solution. However, the final element of trying to apply the string element to the data key doesn't seem to be working. I get "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Original code:

```
$.getJSON('myDataUrl', function(data) {
if ($("#title").length){document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=data.title};
if ($("#noun").length){document.getElementById("noun").innerHTML=data.noun};
if ($("#_id").length){document.getElementById("_id").innerHTML=data._id};
if ($("#owner_id").length){document.getElementById("owner_id").innerHTML=data.owner_id};
});
```

The more 'elegant' solution I'm trying to reach:

```
$.getJSON('myDataUrl', function(data) {
var contentString = "name,noun,_id,owner_id";
var splitContent;
splitContent = contentString.split(",");
for(i = 0; i < splitContent.length; i++)
           {if ($("#" + splitContent[i]).length){
               document.getElementById(splitContent[i]).innerHTML=data.splitContent[i];
               };
               }
```

Comment: You don't need to check for length if using jQuery

Comment: I went by this accepted answer to check if a div exists http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery

Comment: You don't need to check for element existence using jQuery because empty jQuery object can still be handled without throwing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like should be enough:

```
$.getJSON('myDataUrl', function (data) {
    for (var k in data) {
        $("#" + k).html(data[k]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. And makes my 'elegant' idea look like my grandma in high heels. I'll mark as answered once the time limit expires

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `data.splitContent[i]`. That should be `data[splitContent[i]]`. That is, you want to use the current key (e.g. `name`) as a key in the data object.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use jQuery's Map.

```
  $.map(data, function(value, key) {
    $("#" + key).html(value);
  });
```

Here's the working JSBin : http://jsbin.com/tocege/2/edit?html,js,output